# Как отправить нотификацию после закрытия popup'a?

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-extension

Всем привет! Не могу понять следующее: у меня есть расширение с одним окошком, при нажатии на одну из кнопок начинает выполняться функция. В ней таймер, который отправляет периодически запросы к странице и как только получает 200, то создает нотификашку. При открытом попапе всё отлично отрабатывает, но как только его закрываешь - тишина. Как сделать так, чтобы функция и таймер в ней продолжили работать?
В манифесте про фоновый процесс:

```
"background": {
"persistant": true,
"scripts": ["popup.js"]
},
```

Answer (score 1):

При закрытии окна попапа это окно уничтожается. Если тебе нужно запустить периодический процесс - делай его в бэкграунде.
Не понятно какой код у тебя в попапе, а какой в бэкграунде.
При нажатии на кнопку - получай доступ к окну бэкграунда и вызывай функцию из бэкграунда, которая, например запустит `setInterval`

P.S. не называй скрипт `"popup.js"` если это на самом деле background